# SwiftUI State value doesn't change

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-state

I am not familiar with `State`. I tested the code:

```
import SwiftUI
class TestState {
    @State var a: Int = 3
    func increaseA() {
        print("before \(a)") //3
        a += 1
        print("after \(a)") //3?
    }
}

TestState().increaseA()
```

It happens that the printed value are both 3!
Where did I do wrong?

After the comment that `State` should be in a `View`, I tested the code:

```
import SwiftUI
struct TestState: View {
    @State var a: Int = 3
    func increaseA() {
        print("before \(a)")
        a += 1
        print("after \(a)")
    }

    var body: some View {
        increaseA()
        return Text(a.description)
    }
}
```

It happens that the `Text` show "3", not "4". I don't understand.

Comment: `@State` should live within SwfitUI view, not in ordinary class.

Comment: @Asperi, I was curious, so tried it out, and changing it to a View didn't change the behavior. Maybe `@State` depends on some other SwiftUI context?

Comment: Of course it does - I think you'd better start from https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/tutorials

Comment: I think the Xcode hint: "Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior" explains the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@State** keyword was first intrroduced in Swift5.1, it's a @propertyWrapper, has previously been called **@propertyDelegate**. For more details check [property-wrappers.md](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md). 
[AS PAUL HUDSON](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/swiftui-tips-and-tricks) SAID : **@State** is specifically designed for use by the local view, Apple recommends marking **@State** properties as private to really re-enforce that they aren’t designed to be accessed elsewhere: